# toggle function not working with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery

i was using toggle function with jquery 1.7 and it was working fine . I switched to jquery 1.9 and my toggle function stopped working . My function is . THe strange part is the `show()` and `hide()` are working i checked it from dev tools

```
$('#showRight').toggle(
 function(){
  $(".rightflyout").show();
  $("#cbp-spmenu-s2").css('width','238px');
}
,
function(){
  $(".rightflyout").hide();
  $("#cbp-spmenu-s2").css('width','0px');
}
);
```

Comment: That's because toggle was removed in 1.9 :) http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: i tried using jquery `on` but was not able to achieve what i was trying to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from jquery 1.9 docs

> .toggle(function, function, ... ) removed
>
> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions"
>   signature of .toggle(). It should not be confused with the "change the
>   visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated. The
>   former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential
>   for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used
>   to restore the functionality.

Comment: We were closing it as exact duplicate, why do you make an answer from what was already in comments ?

Comment: I was pasting this answer at the same time as comment

Comment: @dystroy - i added a vote to close